# linq , string to chunks

Tags: string, linq, chunks

I need to split string to chunks by linq

example
I want to cut this word(Like) too chunks and the length of each chunk is 2 letters

the result will be
Li ik ke

there is sequences here.

Please, advise me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string s = "Like";    
string s2 = String.Join(" ", s.Select((x, index) => (index+1) == s.Length ? "" : String.Concat(x, s[index+1])));
```

**UPDATE**

By the way, the same problem could be solved with Regex:

```
string s3 = Regex.Replace(s, @"\w", m => m.NextMatch().Success ? m.Value + m.NextMatch().Value + " " : "").TrimEnd();
```